# Are all non-printable characters control characters?

Tags: perl, unicode, control-characters

Does this ([perldoc unicode](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlunicode.html#Unicode-Character-Properties)) mean that all non-printable characters are control-characters?

```
\p{Print}

This matches any character that is graphical or blank, except controls.
```

Comment: What is the precise definition of a "control" character?

Comment: I was not sure about the sentence - it sounds to me that controls are a part from graphical/blank.

Comment: Unicode property "\p{Cntrl}".

Comment: @DVK That would be the Unicode `General_Category=Control` character property, aka `gc=Cc`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If invisible whitespace/blank characters are considered printable, then yes, that only leaves control characters as unprintable.

But if you don't consider whitespace/blank characters such as [line separator](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2028/index.htm) printable, then no.

Answer (score 4):

This will tell you for sure:

```
diff -U0 \
      <( unichars -au '\P{Print}'   ) \
      <( unichars -au '\p{Control}' ) \
   && echo No differences
```

`unichars` comes from [Unicode::Tussle](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Unicode%3a%3aTussle)

I can't run it before Monday.

Comment: `unichars -gas '\P{print}' '\P{control}'` shows that there are two such code points, U+2028 GC=Zl `LINE SEPARATOR` and U+2029 GC=Zp `PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR`.

Comment: Thanks. The DB_File dependency of one of the dependencies is problematic.