# Substitution: "\p{Cntrl}" - "\P{Print}"

Tags: regex, perl, unicode, character-properties

Until now I use these two substitutions before printing "$string" to the terminal.

```
$string =~ s/\p{Space}/ /g;
$string =~ s/\p{Cntrl}//g;
```

Is there something that I should consider, when I replace the first two substitutions with the following two?

```
$string =~ s/\p{Space}/ /g;
$string =~ s/\P{Print}//g;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11590810/are-all-non-printable-characters-control-characters). There are two code points that are neither control nor printable characters: U+2028 `LINE SEPARATOR` and U+2029 `PARAGRAPH SEPARATOR`. But both of them are space characters, so your two substitutions should be equivalent.